# SQL return 2 different dates from one field using Max

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm running the below query to bring back max date where value = 1. I ran into an issue though when I'm trying to return the max date a second time where value = 0 and displaying this result in a separate column. Running SQL in Vulcan database. My query is:

```
select '1' AS client, max(fielddate) AS 'Value1Date' from table1 where 
Value = 1
UNION
select '2' AS client, max(fielddate) AS 'Value1Date' from table2 where 
Value = 1
UNION
select '3' AS client, max(fielddate) AS 'Value1Date' from table3 where 
Value = 1
```

This gives me:

```
Client    Value1Date
1          03/01/17
2          02/01/17
3          02/01/17
```

My issue is trying to get:

```
Client    Value1Date     Value2Date
1          03/01/17       05/01/2017
2          02/01/17       05/07/2017
3          02/01/17       05/09/2017
```

the Value2Date would be similar to the above except max(fielddate) AS 'Value2Date' would not have the value = 1 portion.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: What about `Group By` clause?

Comment: Are those literally how the dates are stored?  Are they being stored as `VARCHAR`?  If it is, you should either change the datatype of your column to be a `DATE` or you will have to `CONVERT` the values to a `DATE` before doing a `MAX()` on them.  Otherwise, your results will not be what you're expecting.

Comment: on which condition value2date is based?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you do want to get on Value2Date. You should show the sample records and fields on table1, table2 and table3 that should get the expected result you have shown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select '1' AS client,
       max(case when value = 1 then fielddate end) AS Value1Date,
       max(fieldDate) as max_fieldDate
from table1 ;
```

Note:  Your question suggests that you are storing different client data in different tables with the same structure.  This is a bad idea, in general, from a data modeling and performance perspective.

Comment: This did it, thank you Gordon! Regarding your note, yes this is the case, clients with the same structure are being stored in different tables, it's a test environment where a number of analysts will load all of their separate clients and can modify/test without affecting anyone else's clients. I was trying to write something to quickly check a number of values across the tables. With the additional details is this still a bad idea to have the data stored like this? I appreciate your input!

Comment: @user1570257 . . . Probably.  If analysts need their own workspaces, they can use views or copy data from a master table down to their own workspaces.